# How can I convert currency symbol to code?

Tags: python, currency

I am trying to convert some price given in pounds and USD into EURO. Is there a Python package which can convert the symbol to code? Which can replace the following function call `convert_sym_to_code(currency_symbol)`?

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
curconv = CurrencyRates()
princess=["$12", "£23"]

for price in princess:
   m = re.search("\d", price)
   currency_symbol = price[0:m.start()]
   tmp = price[m.start():]

   currency_code = convert_sym_to_code(currency_symbol)
   print curconv.convert(currency_code, 'EUR', float(tmp))
```

Comment: Convert it to *what* "code"?

Comment: Currency code, such as EUR, USD, GBP ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A naive approach would be to just use a dictionary:

```
CURRENCY_MAPPING = [
    '$': 'USD',
    '£': 'GBP',
]

def convert_sym_to_code(currency_symbol):
    try:
        CURRENCY_MAPPING[currency_symbol.strip()]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError('Unknown symbol "%s" % currency_symbol)
```

This will fail if you ever encounter any unknown symbol, but it could easily be extended. More importantly, you calculation will be wrong if `$` is used to designate e.g. Australian Dollar.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you just need a mapping from symbol to code, so the "convert_sym_to_code" would be quite trivial - except that quite a few currencies use the same symbol (for example the "$" symbol is used by at least 25 currencies worldwide) so you can't use the symbol as a unique key (unless you're ok to have wrong results of course).